# Modify .xpi of Firefox Add-on SDK extension to run a command on extension startup

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to modify a Firefox extension. There is a "panel.html" page, with an associated "panel.js" file. "Panel.js" seems to export a bunch of classes. I am not sure how it actually executes anything. It is a little hard for me to follow; it seems cryptic and I haven't worked with JavaScript in this way. Basically, there is a switch that I want to automatically toggle "on" when Firefox is opened.

I have no experience with Firefox extension development. It seems that "bootstrap.js" is sandboxed. Therefore, when I try to import "panel.js," I get errors such as "document not defined." I have gotten the switch to toggle on when you click the panel icon and it opens up, but I need this to happen when Firefox opens.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Bootstrap.js

```
const { utils: Cu } = Components;
const rootURI = __SCRIPT_URI_SPEC__.replace("bootstrap.js", "");
const COMMONJS_URI = "resource://gre/modules/commonjs";
const { require } = Cu.import(COMMONJS_URI + "/toolkit/require.js", {});
const { Bootstrap } = require(COMMONJS_URI + "/sdk/addon/bootstrap.js");
var { startup, shutdown, install, uninstall } = new Bootstrap(rootURI);
```

Panel.js

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
//  Created by Valentin Shergin.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 AnchorFree. All rights reserved.
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
  value: true
});

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { 'default': obj }; }

var _WdgtUniversalPipePipeOut = require('Wdgt/../universal/pipe/PipeOut');

var _WdgtUniversalPipePipeOut2 = _interopRequireDefault(_WdgtUniversalPipePipeOut);

var promise = null;

function remoteCakeTubeSDK() {
  if (!promise) {
    promise = new _WdgtUniversalPipePipeOut2['default']('CakeTubeSDK');
  }

  return promise;
}

exports['default'] = remoteCakeTubeSDK;
module.exports = exports['default'];

},{"Wdgt/../universal/pipe/PipeOut":12}],
```

(There are around 200 more exports after this)
Relevant class:

```
42:[function(require,module,exports){
//  Created by Valentin Shergin.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 AnchorFree. All rights reserved.
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
  value: true
});

var _createClass = (function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ('value' in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; })();

var _get = function get(_x, _x2, _x3) { var _again = true; _function: while (_again) { var object = _x, property = _x2, receiver = _x3; _again = false; if (object === null) object = Function.prototype; var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, property); if (desc === undefined) { var parent = Object.getPrototypeOf(object); if (parent === null) { return undefined; } else { _x = parent; _x2 = property; _x3 = receiver; _again = true; desc = parent = undefined; continue _function; } } else if ('value' in desc) { return desc.value; } else { var getter = desc.get; if (getter === undefined) { return undefined; } return getter.call(receiver); } } };

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { 'default': obj }; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function'); } }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== 'function' && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError('Super expression must either be null or a function, not ' + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

require('./ToolbarConnectionSwitcher.less');

require('./Spinner.less');

var _CommonSwitcherSwitcher = require('../Common/Switcher/Switcher');

var _CommonSwitcherSwitcher2 = _interopRequireDefault(_CommonSwitcherSwitcher);

var _remoteCakeTubeSDK = require('remoteCakeTubeSDK');

var _remoteCakeTubeSDK2 = _interopRequireDefault(_remoteCakeTubeSDK);

var _react = require('react');

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

var _PanelController = require('../PanelController');

var _PanelController2 = _interopRequireDefault(_PanelController);

var _reactSpinner = require('react-spinner');

var _reactSpinner2 = _interopRequireDefault(_reactSpinner);

var ToolbarConnectionSwitcher = (function (_Component) {
  _inherits(ToolbarConnectionSwitcher, _Component);

  function ToolbarConnectionSwitcher() {
    var _this = this;

    _classCallCheck(this, ToolbarConnectionSwitcher);

    _get(Object.getPrototypeOf(ToolbarConnectionSwitcher.prototype), 'constructor', this).call(this);

    this.state = {
      connected: true
    };

    this.cakeTubeSDK().then(function (CakeTubeSDK) {
      CakeTubeSDK.connectionService.dispatcher.register(_this.handleConnectionService.bind(_this));
    });

    //**********************************
    //Here I can add this line to make it connect when the panel is opened
    this.handleConnect();
    //**********************************

    this.checkConnectionStatus();
  }

  _createClass(ToolbarConnectionSwitcher, [{
    key: 'cakeTubeSDK',
    value: function cakeTubeSDK() {
      return (0, _remoteCakeTubeSDK2['default'])();
    }
  }, {
    key: 'checkConnectionStatus',
    value: function checkConnectionStatus() {
      var _this2 = this;

      this.cakeTubeSDK().then(function (CakeTubeSDK) {
        return CakeTubeSDK.connectionService.getStatus().then(function (status) {
          var connectingOrDisconnecting = status == 'connecting' || status == 'disconnecting';
          var connected = status == 'connected';

          _this2.refs.self.getDOMNode().classList.toggle('connecting-or-disconnecting', connectingOrDisconnecting);

          if (!connectingOrDisconnecting) {
            _this2.setState({ connected: connected });
            _this2.refs.switcher.setState({ state: connected });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }, {
    key: 'handleConnectionService',
    value: function handleConnectionService() {
      this.checkConnectionStatus();
    }
  }, {
    key: 'handleConnect',
    value: function handleConnect() {
      var _this3 = this;

      this.cakeTubeSDK().then(function (CakeTubeSDK) {
        return CakeTubeSDK.connectionService.connect().then(function () {
          _this3.checkConnectionStatus();
        });
      })['catch'](function (error) {
        _this3.reportError(error);
      });
    }
  }, {
    key: 'handleDisconnect',
    value: function handleDisconnect() {
      var _this4 = this;

      this.cakeTubeSDK().then(function (CakeTubeSDK) {
        return CakeTubeSDK.connectionService.disconnect().then(function () {
          _this4.checkConnectionStatus();
        });
      })['catch'](function (error) {
        _this4.reportError(error);
      });
    }
  }, {
    key: 'handleSignOut',
    value: function handleSignOut() {
      var _this5 = this;

      this.cakeTubeSDK().then(function (CakeTubeSDK) {
        return CakeTubeSDK.connectionService.disconnect().then(CakeTubeSDK.clientService.logOut());
      })['catch'](function (error) {
        _this5.reportError(error);
      });
    }
  }, {
    key: 'reportError',
    value: function reportError(error) {
      this.checkConnectionStatus();
      _PanelController2['default'].panelController().showProblem(error);
    }
  }, {
    key: 'handleSwitcherChanged',
    value: function handleSwitcherChanged() {
      var switcher = this.refs.switcher;
      var state = !!switcher.state.state;

      if (state) {
        this.handleDisconnect();
      } else {
        this.handleConnect();
      }
    }
  }, {
    key: 'render',
    value: function render() {
      var rvalue = _react2['default'].createElement(
        'div',
        { className: 'toolbar-connection-switcher', ref: 'self' },
        _react2['default'].createElement(_CommonSwitcherSwitcher2['default'], { ref: 'switcher', onChanged: this.handleSwitcherChanged.bind(this) }),
        _react2['default'].createElement(
          'div',
          { className: 'spinner' },
          _react2['default'].createElement(_reactSpinner2['default'], null)
        )
      );
      return rvalue;
    }
  }]);

  return ToolbarConnectionSwitcher;
})(_react.Component);

exports['default'] = ToolbarConnectionSwitcher;
module.exports = exports['default'];

},{"../Common/Switcher/Switcher":21,"../PanelController":31,"./Spinner.less":41,"./ToolbarConnectionSwitcher.less":43,"react":206,"react-spinner":51,"remoteCakeTubeSDK":1}],43:[function(require,module,exports){
(function() { var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; var style = document.createElement('style'); style.type = 'text/css';var css = ".toolbar-connection-switcher{position:absolute;top:11px;right:11px}.toolbar-connection-switcher .switcher{opacity:1}.toolbar-connection-switcher .spinner{position:absolute;top:13px;left:6px;pointer-events:none;opacity:0}.toolbar-connection-switcher .switcher,.toolbar-connection-switcher .spinner{transition:opacity .25s}.toolbar-connection-switcher.connecting-or-disconnecting .switcher{opacity:0}.toolbar-connection-switcher.connecting-or-disconnecting .spinner{opacity:1}";if (style.styleSheet){ style.styleSheet.cssText = css; } else { style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css)); } head.appendChild(style);}())
},{}],
```

Comment: You definitely need to provide the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

This an *.xpi* file generated for an Add-on SDK extension using [`jpm xpi`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#jpm_xpi).  You will need to look in the file *package.json*.  The value of property `main` in that file will tell you the name of the file which is always run on Firefox startup or the install/enable of this add-on.

The *bootstrap.js* that you have shown is the exact same code that is contained in all Add-on SDK extensions that have been created using that version of `jpm`.

You should **not** modify *bootstrap.js*. In any Add-on SDK extension like this one, that file sets up the environment for the Add-on SDK extension and through the functions assigned to `startup`, `shutdown`, `install`, `uninstall` (with `var { startup, shutdown, install, uninstall } = new Bootstrap(rootURI);`) runs the code contained in the file pointed to by the `main` property defined in *package.json* when the add-on is first installed, enabled, or Firefox is started (and other times).

Your question lacks enough information to provide more detailed information as to how to accomplish what you desire. For instance, we have no idea what the complete code really is (you have not provided a link to the actual extension). In addition, we do not know what the "switch" is which you want to have automatically toggled to on. This may not even be the most appropriate method of accomplishing what you desire.  Effectively, you have not provided enough information for us to determine what it is that you actually desire to happen.